# Творческий тупик с ассоциативным массивом в PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Логирую такую информацию в серверном скрипте PHP:

> var_dump(substr($Data, 2)): string(14) "{"65535":"??"}"
>
> $Request = (array)json_decode(substr($Data, 2));
>
> var_dump($Request): array(1) { ["65535"]=> string(2) "??" }
>
> var_dump($RequestKeys): array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "65535" }
>
> var_dump($Key): string(5) "65535"
>
> Notice: Undefined index: 65535 in D:\Programms\OpenServer\domains\localhost\WS\index.php on line 147

На 147-й строке такой код:

```
switch($Request[$Key][0]){
```

То есть, мне нужен первый символ элемента массива с ключом $Key, который согласно логам равен строке "65535", и получен он был из того же $Request.

**Как этот элемент может быть "Undefined index"-ом в $Request-е, из которого он и был взят???** Я пробовал и strval($Key), и intval($Key) - всё равно не определённый элемент.

*PS: ключи перебираются в цикле `foreach($RequestKeys as $Key)` для сравнения с другим массивом на предмет одинаковых ключей для выполнения определённых действий.*

Comment: А `$Request[$Key]` что возвращает?

Comment: NULL возвращает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$jSonArray = json_decode($Data, true); //Создаст ассоциативный массив из данных, которые пришли в формате json

foreach ($RequestKeys as $key) {
    if (array_key_exists((int)$key, $jSonArray)) {
        var_dump($jSonArray[(int)$key]); //Вернет нужное Вам значение
    }
}
```

Проверка `array_key_exists()` позволит избежать ошибки, если в массиве не будет нужного Вам ключа

Comment: Но оно преобразует строковое значение с числом в int!! Нет каких-нибудь флагов, чтобы оставить строку строкой?

Comment: А чем Вам мешают числа? Если проблема в том что `$key` - строковое значение, используйте такой метод - `(int)$key`

Comment: Да тем, что данные должны быть как-то унифицированы. Серверу потом отдавать в Javascript данные, а там придётся разбирать строка оно или число после JSON.parse. А вообще не понятно, почему оно не ест строковый индекс... json_decode с параметром true конечно убрал сообщение об ошибке, и индекс находится, но система от этого не заработала - теперь разбираться где какие данные надо преобразовывать в другие типы